How to access child refs in vue
How can I access $refs that is a child of another $refs?
My code looks like this, and what I want to do is to be able to access the ref 'ipsum' with a syntax similar to what I have tried. Of course, I can just do this.$refs.ipsum but that won't work since I have multiple of them.
<script>
  export default {
    mounted() {
      console.log(this.$refs.lorem) // works ofc
      console.log(this.$refs.lorem.$refs.ipsum) //not working 
      console.log(this.$refs.dolor.$refs.ipsum) //not working 
    }
  }
</script>

<template>
  <div ref="lorem">
    <div ref="ipsum">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div ref="dolor">
    <div ref="ipsum">
    </div>
  </div>
</template>


Not sure what you're trying to achieve here as a whole, but I feel like this is not the way to go. Also, don't you have a children property on the first ref element? Inspect it in your console, should find something in there. Please also remember that refs are not reactive in Vue2, in case you plan on having something involving such a thing.

You can use
this.$refs.ipsum[0] or this.$refs.ipsum[1].
If the refs are pointing to components, eg. this.$refs.lorem is a component containing $refs.ipsum then you can use this.$refs.lorem.$refs.ipsum[0]
